# Rendering different part of templates according to the request values in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

In my view to render my template I receive different parameters through my request.

According to these parameters I need to render different "part" in my templates.

For example let say that if I receive in my request

```
to_render = ["table", "bar_chart"]
```

I want to render a partial template for table and an other for bar_chart

```
to_render = ["bar_chart", "line_chart"]
```

Then I will want to render a partial template for the bar_chart and an other for line_chart

Can I define this in my view?

Or do I have to manage this in my template?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just manage it in your template

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can manage this in your view. The [template API](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#ref-templates-api) shows clearly how to use the templating system in Python.