# Django: render template based on request data with class-based views

Tags: django, django-views

**What I am trying to do:**

generate page with some default input date values and generate some data based on those values.
When new data values are chosen, we generate updated data.

I am using class-based views considering structure of application which I would like to extend.

**What is not working:**

templates are rendered, but I can't get dynamically values of 'start' and 'end' to generate updated the data.

**My question:**

Is such structure correct and logical in terms of Django standard practices? Can you please point out where my code is incorrect?

My question is related to this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592331/rendering-different-part-of-templates-according-to-the-request-values-in-django). But I would like to keep all logic in the views.

Thank you very much.

Here is a bit simplified code:

index.html

```
   {% extends "base.html" %} 
   {% block main %}
        {% include "_usage.html" %}
        {{ generated_data }}
        {{ table.render }}
    {% endblock %}
```

_usage.html

```
<div class="name">
    <span>From: <input id="id_start" name="start" type="text" value="{{ start }}"></span>
    <span>To: <input id="id_end" name="end" type="text" value="{{ end }}"</span>
    <button class="name" type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', GenericView.as_view(), name='index'),
)
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic.base import View
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse

class UsageView(View):
    template_name = '_usage.html'
    default_start = '2014-01-01'
    default_end = '2014-01-02'

    def get(self, request):
        data_dict = {'start': self.default_start, 'end': self.default_end}
        response = TemplateResponse(request, self.template_name, data_dict)
        return response

class GenericView(UsageView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get(self, request):
        super(GenericView, self).get(request)

        start_value = request.GET['start']
        end_value = request.GET['end']
        values = '1, 2, 3'

        data_dict = {'start': start_value, 'end': end_value, 'generated_data': values}

        response = TemplateResponse(request, self.template_name, data_dict)
        return response
```

Comment: How does `_usage.html` work? It doesn't seem to have any HTML for a form.

Comment: Sorry for lack of clarity. I updated my question. There is a base.html file which I extend. It has all html code required for basic html page generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong here.

Firstly, your `super` call in GenericView is pointless - you call the super function, but then throw the result away. But you couldn't actually do anything with that return value anyway, because it is returning a rendered response, rather than context values which you could then use to render the template.

Rather than subclassing `View` and overriding `get`, you should be overriding `TemplateView` and overriding `get_context_data`: then your method can simply be concerned with setting the relevant values, and the view itself will take care of rendering the template.

Secondly, you don't have an actual form element in _usage.html. That means the submit button won't do anything, so you won't ever receive your field values in request.GET. You need to wrap the fields with `<form action="." method="GET"> ... </form>`.